# Can I be copyrighted for using a scream in my song?

Tags: copyright

I found this video of Yoko Ono screaming at some art show on YouTube and I thought that it would resemble fabulously with a song I was making at the time. The video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdZ9weP5i68&ab_channel=GrandmasterofWin) was recorded by some fan and not someone from Yoko’s crew so I don’t think that there should be any copyright issues when released on streaming platforms such as Spotify, etc. but I want to make sure that it’ll be 100% copyright free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somebody owns the copyright to that recording, which means that you have to have their permission to use it in your work. Without permission, you can be sued for copyright infringement. You would have to contact the person who made the recording, or their agent: it might be "some fan". The obvious first step is to hire an attorney to do the relevant research for you.

Answer (score 2):

### The person who recorded the scream owns the copyright

Copyright belongs to the person who first caused the work to be fixed in a tangible form, in this case, a sound recording.

For the case of a spontaneous utterance or sound, the person operating the recording device is the sole copyright owner, just like the person who takes a cameo photograph owns that copyright. Where the performers have come together for the purpose of being recorded, they will create a joint work with the technician and the producer (there will usually be contracts spelling this out precisely), but that’s not the case here.

You need to find “some fan” and ask their permission.

Comment: In this case, however, the "scream" was not a spontaneous utterance but a work of performance art for which Yoko Ono is most likely entitled to copyright protection.

Comment: @phoog and most likely there *is* an official recording of it.